# "From File" Simulink block called from Matlab .m file in loop

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am calling a Simulink simulation through a loop in Matlab. I am able to send many numerical parameters (initial conditions for integrators for example), but an error arises in my "From File" block.

I'm not quite sure how other people do it, but where I work we send it through a home-built function which takes a structure input. The fields of the structure are the variable names and the values of the fields are the variables themselves. for example:

```
pb = struct('preload',preload(pl_index),...
            'displacement',preload_displacement(pl_index),...
            'filename',fileList{m});
```

The 'preload' and 'displacement' variables evaluate fine, but the `filename` gives an error:

```
filename.mat
```

Does anyone know **if you can** pass the value of the variable `filename` (`fileList{m}`) in the 'From File' block and if so, **how to do it**. Thanks!

Comment: filename is used as a string parameter and is not evaluated as a variable. You would need to do set_param('from_file_block','filename',fileList{m}) for this to work.

Comment: Yes I agree, however with the script we're using at work I'm not sure if that would be possible... Good point though, thanks. @Navan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question!

I used the Simulink "From Workspace" block instead of "From File".

```
f = load(fileList{m});
fnames = fieldnames(f);
% The files were arranged weird, so I have one field inside the structures... and they all had different names.
    switch fnames{1}
        case 'first'
            filedata = f.first;
        case 'second'
            filedata = f.second;
        case 'third'
            filedata = f.third;
        case 'fourth'
            filedata = f.fourth;
    end
    t = filedata(1,:);
    u = filedata(2,:);

loaded_file = timeseries(u,t);
```

And I pass `loaded_file` to my function.